# MODI.Image from (Bitmap) Image NOT saved on hard disk.

Tags: c#, ocr, emgucv, modi

i'm coding an OCR MODI application for numbers recognition.
It works quite well but i'm trying to speed it up.

I need to create a MODI.Document or a MODI.Image directly from a Emgu.CV.UI.ImageBox and without loading it from the hard disk.

Something like

```
MODI.Document md = new MODI.Document();
md.Create(my_picture_box.Image.Bitmap);
```

or

```
MODI.IImage my_image = new MODI.IImage(my_picture_box.Image.Bitmap)
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a temp file to make MODI read the Bitmap. Sadly there is no way of reading it from the memory.

If you are using your programm only on a Windows Server you could use a RAMDisc to make it read and write the file faster.